# Apple Xcode: remapping camera's Pan, Orbit and Dolly controls in SceneKit module

Tags: keyboard, xcode, mouse, swift

I'd like to remap the following camera controls in SceneKit module of Xcode 9.2 (I'm coding in Swift):

***panning***  – <kbd>alt</kbd> + LMB

***orbiting*** – LMB

***dollying*** – <kbd>alt</kbd> + MMB

**Pan** drags the virtual camera along the XY plane, **Orbit** rotates the camera around Y axis and **Dolly** moves the camera forward and backward along local Z axis.

[image]

> Is it possible to reassign mouse hotkeys for pan, orbit and dolly operations in Xcode's module SceneKit the same way as it works in Autodesk Maya?

***panning***  – <kbd>alt</kbd> + MMB

***orbiting*** – <kbd>alt</kbd> + LMB

***dollying*** – <kbd>alt</kbd> + RMB

Comment: There's no need to repeatedly edit your question so much, see [Can, and if yes, should posts be bumped?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2731/can-and-if-yes-should-posts-be-bumped)